# WSA logcat logging is filling out my disk

Tags: logcat, windows-subsystem-for-android

I have developed few android apps in the past and possibly enabled debugging mode and then disabled it. I had also trying to diagnose a freezing issue in WSA before a while and might have enabled more logging via adb but I can't recall what I have done before.

The issue I had now is that WSA logcat is unreasonabily creating hundreds of gigabytes of logs when I'm using WSA for normal activity (not development). Please tell me how to disable this extremely verbose logging as I am a bit lost.

[image]

[image]

located in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\diagnostics\logcat`

[image]

I noticed most of the repeated logs is similar to the sample below:

```
nBroadcast:3051 com.android.server.ConnectivityService.updateInetCondition:9196 
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.174   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.175   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
10-05 07:48:50.175   256   257 E virtualinputservice: Failed to write input event: Bad file descriptor.
```

I have disabled verbose logging in the Android settigns. I also went in adb shell and checked the `adb logcat -g` and found the buffer default size is 256kb. Worth noting `adb logcat -c` didn't clear the logs in the logcat folder, it seems to be logs generated from another source.

I just want to disable the logging or atleast make it rotate with max log size of 256mb. Maybe a solution would be to stop the reason for that log message that keeps being spammed.